# React Hooks(useEffect) form Sub mission

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api, use-effect, react-hook-form

I am trying to create a react form to submit a post to an array of posts that is in a mock API. here I use effect and fetch API,
in the post component, I am listing all posts and it's showing properly,
I am having some issues when submitting my form, if anyone can know, please check.

my code is below

> app js

```
import React from 'react';
import Addpost from './Addpost';
import './App.css';
import Post from './Post';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Addpost />
        <Post />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> post js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
//https://5f61813d07c1770016c52193.mockapi.io/posts/
function Post() {
  const [post, setPost] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const req = await fetch(
        "https://5f61813d07c1770016c52193.mockapi.io/posts/"
      ).then((r) => r.json());

      setPost(req);
      //console.log(req);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);



  return (
    <div>
      
      {post?.map((p, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <h3>{p.title}</h3> {p.body} <br /> <br /> <br />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Post;
```

> addpost js

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Addpost() {
  const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
  const [title, SetTilte] = useState("");
  const [body, SetBody] = useState("");
  const [id, SetId] = useState();
  const [userId, setuserId] = useState();

  let new_post = {
    title: title,
    body: body,
    id: id,
    userId: userId,
  };
  async function postData() {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ title: "submited" }),
    };
    const req = await fetch(
      "https://5f61813d07c1770016c52193.mockapi.io/posts/",
      requestOptions
    ).then((r) => r.json());

    setPost(...post, req);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    postData();
  }, []);

  function handleSub(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    postData(new_post);
  }
  return (
    <div className="form">
      <form onSubmit={handleSub}>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={id}
          onChange={(e) => SetId(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="number"
          value={userId}
          onChange={(e) => setuserId(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input value={title} onChange={(e) => SetTilte(e.target.value)} />
        <input value={body} onChange={(e) => SetBody(e.target.value)} />

        <button>submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Addpost;
```

Error message which is showing up in chrome console

```
5f61813d07c1770016c52193.mockapi.io/posts/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
index.js:1 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type number to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. 
    in input (at Addpost.js:41)
    in form (at Addpost.js:40)
    in div (at Addpost.js:39)
    in Addpost (at App.js:9)
    in div (at App.js:8)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
5f61813d07c1770016c52193.mockapi.io/posts/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the posts to API, I think it's more of a API issue than the front-end. The return data is saying you've exceeded maximum elements

[image]

---

With regards to the console error

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type number
> to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled
> to controlled (or vice versa)

Just initialize your state such that the `value` of the `input` components is already controlled initially and not undefined. e.g., empty strings

```
const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
const [title, SetTilte] = useState("");
const [body, SetBody] = useState("");
const [id, SetId] = useState("");
const [userId, setuserId] = useState("");
```

Answer (score 1):

> for finxig this error please set you inputs type to text like below code

```
<input type="text" value={title} onChange={(e) => SetTilte(e.target.value)} />
<input type="text" value={body} onChange={(e) => SetBody(e.target.value)} />
```

i think your code have more problems, after fixing above problem ,commenting if you have more problems

Comment: hey Shahbaz, updated as per your advice, still having the same issues,  
below error is showing up
index.js:1 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type number to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: